# What is the answer for question 19 in The Impossible Quiz?

Tags: the-impossible-quiz

[image]
This doesn't even make any sense! What does this riddle mean? What is the answer?

Comment: Confused why you decided to put this question up here in the first place.

Comment: Why would you be confused? What makes this question a bad one? @Waterseas

Comment: To me this is a good question.

Comment: Many people might not understand this  question on the impossible quiz and this answer could potentially be useful to them.

Comment: @Scribblenautical It's not closing material definitely, but posting a single question out of the ridiculousness that is the impossible quiz when you already know the answer seems strange to me.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/  Even the site says it is okay to answer your own questions. As I said before, it might potentially help others in the future. @Waterseas

Comment: @Scribblenautical I know you're able to answer your own questions, just commening that it's really strange to pick this one question out of all the ridiculous and difficult questions of the impossible quiz XD

Answer (score 13, accepted):

BOGGY stands for colors on the paint buckets. Each time you put in a color, a portion of his face will be colored in. B is Blue, G is Green, Y is Yellow and O is Orange.

Answer (score 6):

The riddle is simple. Do you see the word Boggy underneath that creature? These letters represent the colors of the paint buckets that you need to click in that order. B for blue, O for Orange, G for Green (x2) and y is for yellow.